# Is there one like py2exe that supports Python 3.x?

Tags: python, py2exe

I understand py2exe supports only Python 2.x but is there one like py2exe that supports Python 3.x?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0

Comment: Guys you don't have merci down-voting a newcomer... It's not ok

Comment: @user1767754 it's a question that can be answered by a quick google search, and in general is not a good fit for stackexchange websites

Comment: @user1767754 *questions* get downvotes, not *users*. There is plenty of material of asking good questions in the Help Center.

Comment: @user1767754 it's even less OK to give sympathy upvotes to a crappy question. Like Jon said, vote on the *question*, not on the user, or the reception it's getting.

Comment: Not everyone is very familiar with our todays internet, even it is a vote on the question, it is as well bound to the user. Flag the question instead, and comment, this will be more beneficial for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest py2exe does support Python 3:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0

Of course, at the time of this writing, the py2exe website doesn't link to this version of py2exe, which is a bit confusing. PyInstaller only support Python 2.4-2.7 according to their [main page](http://www.pyinstaller.org), however they do have a [ticket](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/85) that's 5 years old where they say they are going to add Python 3 compatibility.

I would recommend [cx_freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) as it supports both Python 2.x and 3.x

The [HitchHiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/freezing/) has a good page about freezing your apps, although it's information on py2exe is incorrect.